# JQuery..find closest space and replace with

Tags: jquery, find, substr

I wrote this code here:

```
var title = "This is my comment for my title";
title.replace(/['"`!#()_:\/\.\?]|&[^;]+;/g, '').substring(0, 20);
```

This gets me the first 20 characters, however I want to find the closest space and replace with `...`

How would I do that?

Newbie at JQuery

Right now it returns this... `This is my comment f`, I would like to return `This is my comment...`

I tried adding this code:

```
title = title.substr(title.indexOf(" ")) + "...";
```

but it removed `This` from my variable.

Comment: You should add what the title should look like afterwards.

Comment: It is JavaScript, not jQuery. Newbie to JavaScript would be meaningful.

Comment: how about just tossing in another substring using lastIndexOf space as the 2nd parameter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
title.replace(/\s([^" "]+)$/, '...');
```

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/UwtJQ/2/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you intend to do if there is no space in the first 20 characters, but here's  a possible solution:

```
var result;
if(title.indexOf(" ") > 20){
    // no space in the first 20 characters
    }else{
        result = title.substring(0, title.substring(0,20).lastIndexOf(" ")) + "...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: (i have not used jQuery in this code)

```
var arr = title.replace(/['"`!#()_:\/\.\?]|&[^;]+;/g, '').substring(0, 20).split(" ");
arr.splice(arr.length - 1, 1);
var message = arr.join(" ") + "..."; //the message variable is the string with '...'
```